# SheetJS method to create an Excel file with subheaders

Tags: javascript, excel

The method is fully functional and creates an excel as expected.

What I would like to know, is if can be made more functional and better written for maintainability.

For example, how can I put the headers of the columns in that way to be separated to allow better readability and in this case be able to manipulate single columns in sense of width and so on.

I'm new to XLSX and I was wondering about a better way to write what I did

```
import XLSX from 'xlsx';
import moment from 'moment';

const N_A = null;

const headerGroups = [
  { name: 'Candidate data', origin: 'A1' },
  { name: 'Date receiving status', origin: 'N1' },
  { name: 'Candidate in Pending call center status', origin: 'U1' },
  {
    name: 'Candidate in Pending site OR Consented OR Randomized status',
    origin: 'AI1',
  },
];

const colWidths = [{ wch: 12 }];

const rawToHeaders = ({
  id,
  externalIds,
  dateOfBirth = {},
  postalCode,
  locale,
  siteId,
  status = {},
  prescreenerMetrics,
}) => {
  const { day, month, year } = dateOfBirth;
  const dob = [day, month, year].filter(Boolean).join('-');
  const { type, label, comment, timestamp } = status;
  const timeInStatus = moment(timestamp).toNow(true);
  return {
    // !Candidate data
    'Candidate ID': id,
    'External IDs': externalIds
      ?.map(({ source, value }) => `${source}: ${value}`)
      .join('; '),
    'Date of birth': dob,
    'Postal code': postalCode,
    Locale: locale,
    'Site ID': siteId,
    'PI name': N_A,
    'Current status': type,
    'Current sub-status': label,
    'Current status comment': comment,
    'Time in current status': timeInStatus,
    'Source/recruiter': prescreenerMetrics?.source,
    Referrer: prescreenerMetrics?.referrer,
    // !Date receiving status
    'Pending call center': N_A,
    'Pending site': N_A,
    Consented: N_A,
    Randomized: N_A,
    'Rejected call center': N_A,
    'Rejected  site (+ rejected_consented + rejected_randomized)': N_A,
    'Call Scheduled': N_A,
    // !Candidate in Pending call center status
    'Call - Attempts (by call center)': N_A,
    'SMS - Attempts (by call center)': N_A,
    'Email - Attempts (by call center)': N_A,
    'Phone number revealed (by call center) - quantity': N_A,
    'Email revealed (by call center) - quantity': N_A,
    'Call - date of first attempt (by call center)': N_A,
    'SMS - date of first attempt (by call center)': N_A,
    'Email - date of first attempt (by call center)': N_A,
    'Call - duration of longest call (by call center)': N_A,
    'Call - date of longest call (by call center)': N_A,
    'Comments (by call center) in Trialbee system': N_A,
    'Last staff activity (by call center) - Action': N_A,
    'Last staff activity by call center - User': N_A,
    'Last staff activity by call center - Date': N_A,
    // !Candidate in Pending site OR Consented OR Randomized status
    'Call - attempts (by site)': N_A,
    'SMS - attempts (by site)': N_A,
    'Email - attempts (by site)': N_A,
    'Phone number revealed (by site) - quantity': N_A,
    'Email revealed (by site) - quantity': N_A,
    'Call - date of first attempt (by site)': N_A,
    'SMS - date of first attempt (by site)': N_A,
    'Email - date of first attempt by site': N_A,
    'Call - Longest duration of call (by site)': N_A,
    'Call - Date of longest call (by site)': N_A,
    'Comments (by site) in Trialbee system': N_A,
    'Last staff activity (by site) - Action': N_A,
    'Last staff activity (by site) - User': N_A,
    'Last staff activity (by site) - Date': N_A,
  };
};

const generateMasterReport = (data) => {
  const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data.map(rawToHeaders), { origin: 'A2' });
  ws['!merges'] = [
    XLSX.utils.decode_range('A1:M1'),
    XLSX.utils.decode_range('N1:T1'),
    XLSX.utils.decode_range('U1:AH1'),
    XLSX.utils.decode_range('AI1:AV1'),
  ];
  headerGroups.forEach(({ name, origin }) => {
    XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(ws, [[name]], { origin });
  });

  ws['!cols'] = colWidths;

  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws);

  return XLSX.write(wb, { type: 'buffer', bookType: 'xlsx' });
};

export default generateMasterReport;
```